# files does not load spring-mvc

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp

In my Spring-MVC project, I have `css` and `images` folders under `resources` folder and `resources` folder is under `WEB-INF`. And inside my jsp/view files I am accessing files from these folders like this: `<img src="/resources/images/logo.jpg">` and `<script src="resources/css/myStyle.css">`. But this does not works. So please tell how can I load these files in my `.jsp` file/view.

**Project Directory:**

[image]

Comment: you need to use <c:url > tag for accessing resources. Further more I would keep my static resources out side the WEB-INF

Comment: AFAIK a css is not a script. you need to access it using <link rel="stylesheet" href=".." />

Comment: Maybe you problem is from you deployment. Are you deploying as a WAR if so is your image present at the correct location? Also, i don't see any image under images

Comment: anything in `WEB-INF` isn't publicly accessible so that isn't going to work with some sort of resource handler/config.